# iOS/Android pay licence to use app

Tags: android, ios, payment

I am developing an application for iOS and Android and this app will be free on the store, but to use all features of the app, the user will need to pay a licence every month/year and if he doesn't pay it, he will have only a limited access to the app, with just few features. Moreover, the first month after he registers, he will have full access.

To pay the licence, it'll can be done in the app or on the website.

For that, do I need to develop a function to check on each connection my database to see if the user has paid, or is there already something done. I have look for "in app purchasing" but it seems that it works only for app where we pay once to have full features, and not every month.

Thank you :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is a system in in-app-purchase for this, just check the url: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202023 and "Auto-renewing subscriptions" tab

Answer (score 0):

you can go for in app purchase / in app billing

**iOS**,

> In-App Purchase lets you sell a variety of items directly within your free or paid app, including premium content, virtual goods, and subscriptions. And just like apps you sell on the App Store, you receive 70% of the purchase price.

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

**Android**

> Use In-app Billing to sell digital goods, including one-time items and recurring subscriptions.
>   Supported for any app published on Google Play. You only need a Google Play Developer Console account and a Google payments merchant account.
>   Checkout processing is automatically handled by Google Play, with the same look-and-feel as for app purchases.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html